# Project point cloud to image coordinates using camerainfo

Tags: ros, coordinate-system, image-geometry, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm new to ROS (and PCL as well) so sorry if the question is too trivial...but I've been searching for quite a long time and couldn't find an answer..

I have the pointcloud and I need to project it to the image coordinates with corresponding CameraInfo. I found there is K (intrinsic) matrix which I should use for multiplication the coordinates (K*[x y z]^transposed) but the results don't seem to be correct...

EDIT: Okay, I followed the tutorial and now I have something like

```
PointCloud<PointXYZI>::Ptr output_xyz(new PointCloud<PointXYZI>); // init PointCloud
sensor_msgs::CameraInfo cam_info; // init CameraInfo
.... // do some processing
image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel cam_model; // init cam_model
cam_model.fromCameraInfo(cam_info); // fill cam_model with CameraInfo
cv::Point3d pt_cv(output_xyz->at(0).x, output_xyz->at(0).y, output_xyz->at(0).z);//init Point3d
cv::Point2d uv = cam_model.project3dToPixel(pt_cv); // project 3d point to 2d point
```

and I'm getting an assertion error "Assertion `P_(2, 3) == 0.0' failed" . That is obvious because my cam_model.projectionMatrix() looks like this

```
[868.9074096679688, 0, 641.492403333923, 0;
0, 879.0201416015625, 542.1365647019775, 0;
0, 0, 1, 1]
```

I think there is no problem with CameraInfo, because rviz displays the pointcloud correctly in the image with it, but I probably need to do yet some other manipulation to get the correct result. Don't you know what might be the problem?

Thanks in advance, JP

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135531/project-point-cloud-to-image-coordinates-using-camerainfo/) by [jpo](https://answers.ros.org/users/12791/jpo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2014-03-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend reading the information on the [image_geometry](http://wiki.ros.org/image_geometry) wiki page. If you follow the conventions stated there, you´ll be able to easily use the [project3dToPixel](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/image_geometry/html/c++/classimage__geometry_1_1PinholeCameraModel.html#a30b3761aadfa4b91c7fedb97442c2f13) function to achieve your goal.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3